# Audition Scene: Writing a Book with a audition scene for a child

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, plot, fantasy, child-characters

I want to write an audition scene in my book. The character is eight, turning nine in a few months, and she will be auditioning for the main character role in a child fantasy show. I've never been to an audition except for a school play, way, way back and don't really remember the process except for three judges behind a table.

I've looked all over the web for answers but can't get one, can someone help me.

Comment: There are plenty of children's books that have similar events. Just browse until you find one. (like Harry Potter, Upside Down Magic, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

At the present time there are thousands of professional Hollywood child actors and even more amateur child actors in school plays, and several times as many adults who have auditioned as children or adults.  I think if you asked for stories about typical and/or unusual audition experiences at some sites for actors you might get a number of answers.

For example, former child actor Paul Peterson founded an organization, A Minor Consideration, for helping child actors and former child actors.

[https://www.facebook.com/minorcon[1]](https://www.facebook.com/minorcon%5B1%5D)

And it is possible that a question there about auditions would get some answers.

Also see *Pretty Babies: An Insider's Look at the  World of the Hollywood Child Star*, Andrea Darvi, 1987.